# Redirection from a directory with www to the same directory without www

Tags: redirect

I would like to make a permanent 301 redirection :
from all the html files of
example.com/directory/
to all the html files of
www.example.com/directory/

Comment: What are you using? PHP?

Comment: All pzges are html pages. I am using a .htaccess file to make the redirections (on an Apache server)

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from innumerable sites, after a quick google for *"htaccess remove www"*,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.

My goal is to add www to any urls typed withour such www.

I am currently using the following :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Unfortunately, it only works to redirect example.com to www.example.com

But it does not work to redirect example.com/directory/anyfile.html to www.example.com/directory/anyfile.html

Any idea to redirect example.com/directory/anyfile.html to www.example.com/directory/anyfile.html ?